# How to send a message to another component in a different view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two different components with two different views. The first component is a dashboard with buttons. The second component is a component of the restaurant. How to make a change in the value of the text that will be displayed in the restaurant view when you click on the "accept" button in the dashboard view?

For example, the message window in the restaurant view displays the message "Wait for a message from the restaurant". In the restaurant view, I click "Accept" and the chimney in the restaurant view changes to "Reservation accept"

this is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommunicateService {

private message = new BehaviorSubject('Wait for a message from the restaurant');
currentMessage = this.message.asObservable();

constructor () {}

changeMessage(message: string) {
this.message.next(message);
  }
}
```

this is my dashboard.component.ts

```
import {CommunicateService } from '../../services/communicate.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class DashboardComponent {
message: string;


constructor(private cs: CommunicateService) implements OnInit {}

ngOnInit() {
this.cs.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
}

newMessage() {
this.cs.changeMessage('Reservation accept!');
}
}
```

dasboard.component.html

```
<button (click)="newMessage()">Accept</button>
```

restaurant.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicateService } from '../../../services/communicate.service';

export class RestaurantComponent implements OnInit {

 message: string;


 constructor(private cs: CommunicateService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
 this.cs.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
 }
}
```

and restaurant.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="message" class="alert alert-success">{{message}}</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the part that is throwing the error

Comment: The post has been edited

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: when I click on a button in the dashboard view, the message in the restaurant view doesnt change

Comment: I just created a stackblitz from your code, and it works? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fp58na

Comment: Yes, it only works that the message is on the same page as the button. In my project, the button is in a different view. Not where there is a message that changes. My point is to change the message from another page view. My dashboard is in a different view because it serves as a reservation management panel. And the restaurant component is a separate view.

Comment: Is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it is possible and should be working. The data is flowing through a service. It doesn't matter that the two components are on the same page. I wonder if you are having a issue where the service is not a singleton and is being recreated.

Comment: Can I solve this problem somehow? I really want it to work

Comment: Ok, I've added routes. There is now a dashboard route and restaurant. Everything is still working as expected? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2ntz4

Comment: Ok it works :D !! thank you !